# How to Speed up Computation Time

Tags: performance, math, lua, nested-loops

I have written the following code:

```
combinationsstring = "List of Combinations"
for a = 0, 65 do
    for b = 0, 52 do
        for c = 0, 40 do
            for d = 0, 28 do
                for e = 0, 19 do
                    for f = 0, 11 do
                        for g = 0, 4 do
                            if (((1.15^a)-1)+((20/3)*((1.15^b)-1))
                               +((100/3)*((1.15^c)-1))+(200*((1.15^d)-1))
                               +((2000/3)*((1.15^e)-1))+((8000/3)*((1.15^f)-1))
                               +((40000/3)*((1.15^g)-1))) < 10000 then
                                combinationsstring = combinationsstring
                                    .."\n"..a..", "..b..", "..c..", "..d
                                    ..", "..e..", "..f..", "..g
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

local file = io.open("listOfCombinations.txt", "w")
file:write(combinationsstring)
file:close()
```

I need to find all the sets of data that fit the following equation

```
(((1.15^a)-1)+((20/3)*((1.15^b)-1))+
((100/3)*((1.15^c)-1))+(200*((1.15^d)-1))+
((2000/3)*((1.15^e)-1))+((8000/3)*((1.15^f)-1))+
((40000/3)*((1.15^g)-1))) < 10000
```

each variable (a-g) is a real integer. So I calculated the maximum values for each of the 7 (the maximum for each variable will be when all the other values are 0). These maximum's are 65, 52, 40, 28, 19, 11 and 4 respectfully (62 = a, 52 = b and so on)

So I created 7 nested for loops (as shown in the code above) and in the middle block, i tested the 7 values to see if they fit the criteria, if they did, they were added onto a string. At the end of the code, the program would write over a file and put that final string in containing all the possible combinations.

The program is working fine, however there are 3.1 billion computations carried out over the course of this simulation and from some testing, I found my computer to be averaging 3000 computations per second. This means that the total simulation time is about 12 days and 5 hours. I don't have this time whatsoever, so I had spent all morning simplifying the equation to be tested for, removing unnecessary code and this was my final result.

Is this method I have done using the nested for loops the most optimal method here? If it is, are there any other ways I can speed this up, if not, can you tell me another way?

P.S. I am using Lua because it's the language I am the most familiar with, but if you have other suggestions/examples, use it in your language and I can try optimise it for this program.

Comment: I'm not awake enough to offer suggestions for algorithmic improvement, but one easy thing you can do to get a huge improvement in performance is switching from stock Lua to LuaJIT. One somewhat harder thing is parallelizing your code; this is what's known as an "embarassingly parallel" problem, where the results are all independent of each other, so using something like Lanes to split your computation into multiple threads should get you nearly linear speedup (until you run out of cores, anyways).

Comment: To the downvoter: would you mind explaining why do you think this is a low-quality question? Even if the OP is clearly not an expert programmer, this is about a very real and specific problem that can be tackled using a program and the attempted solution shows effort and willingness to learn. (+1 for me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't speak lua, but here are a few suggestions:

- Before starting the loop on `b`, compute and store `1.15^a-1`; maybe call it `fooa`.
- Likewise, before starting the loop on `c`, compute `fooa+(20/3)*(1.15^b-1)`; maybe call it `foob`.
- Do similar things before starting each loop.
- If `foob`, for instance, is at least `10000`, break out of the loop; the stuff inside
  can only make the result bigger.
- This might be useless or worse in lua, but do you really need to accumulate the result in a string?  I don't know how lua represents strings and does concatenation, but the concatenation might be hurting you badly.  Try using a list or array data structure instead.

I'd also add that the nested loops are a perfectly sensible solution and, with the above modifications, exactly what I would do.

Comment: (+1) I'll add that: (a) concatenation in the inner loop **will** hurt badly, since it hogs the garbage collector with dead strings to be recycled; (b) using an array maybe won't suffice since the memory needed is too big (I tried a naive approach and got an out of memory error); the OP best bet is to write the [a,b,c,d,e,f,g] tuple to file as soon as it is found, although slow. Caching a small set of solutions in a table and then write them out could be better still (c) Lua doesn't optimize expressions, so your suggestion of manually hoisting common subexpressions out of inner loops is good.

Comment: ok, so here is the updated code: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=U1qmCXQc

I can now do roughly 20000 computations per second, that equates to a total of 1 day and 19 hours. I will try run it on Lua JIT now

Comment: I gave this a try and can calculate the whole thing in ~15 minutes using LuaJIT (on a 1.8GHz office machine). Instead of writing every result to the file I store ~500 in a table and flush that out, seems to be a little quicker. Here is the code I used: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=dTLA5V3J

Comment: I tried running that, but it didn't know what t was, how was it initialised?

Comment: EDIT: I just realised that you were using that to time the computation time, I removed it and its running now

Comment: I didn't mean to leave the debug print in there, fixed it.

Comment: Another trick to try is to use table.concat({a,b,c,d,e,f,g},',') to concat the string.

Comment: @JaneT this won't be that useful. The problem is not the garbage generated by the concatenations of these small strings. The problem is `combinationsstring = combinationsstring .. table.concat(`. If `combinationsstring` is already (say) 2Mb long, the concatenation of even a small string will make those 2Mb garbage. Moreover you are allocating a temporary table inside an 7-level-deep inner loop, thus creating zillions of dead tables, this may lead to *worse* performance (i.e. what you save avoiding those `..` you may lose in the temp table creation/garbage collection).

Comment: Sorry I was not clear,  I would have then put that string in a table and dumped it with table.concat to the file in batches of 500.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a static language for brute-forcing things of this nature. I had a problem ([this one](http://domino.research.ibm.com/Comm/wwwr_ponder.nsf/Challenges/July2013.html)) that I was having trouble with using python but the C++ brute force 8-for-loop approach computes the solution in 30 seconds.

Comment: It's true that C/C++ is faster, but I think it's unfair to compare the speed of Lua with Python. Experiments show that Lua(JIT) is the fastest scripting language.

Comment: I agree. The very specific OP's problem doesn't gain much from being written in Lua, besides being the language he/she knows better. Reimplementing it in C or C++ and compile it with full optimizations could give better results with little additional hassle.

Comment: @YuHao While it is true that LuaJIT is one of the fastest dynamic runtimes, it's quite clear that this fact is not being taken advantage of. You cannot escape the order of magnitude improvement in performance from a statically compiled program when it comes to brute-forcing. If we were talking about some fancy algorithm to write much more easily with lua, then maybe. I say maybe, because C++11 has closures, and when you have a clang integrated IDE to write C++11 with, it's actually pretty quick to write high level programs.

Answer (score 0):

Since you also asked for solutions in different languages, here is a quick and dirty program in C++, also incorporating the suggestions by @tmyklebu.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream os( "listOfCombinations.txt" );
    using std::pow;
    for( double a = 0; a <= 65; ++a ) {
        double aa = (pow(1.15, a) - 1);
        if ( aa > 10000 ) break;
        for( double b = 0; b <= 52; ++b ) {
            double bb = aa + (20/3) * (pow(1.15, b) - 1);
            if ( bb > 10000 ) break;
            for( double c = 0; c <= 40; ++c ) {
                double cc = bb + (100/3) * (pow(1.15, c) - 1);
                if ( cc > 10000 ) break;
                // The following line provides some visual feedback for the
                // user about the progress (it prints current a, b, and c
                // values).
                std::cout << a << "   " << b << "   " << c << std::endl;
                for( double d = 0; d <= 28; ++d ) {
                    double dd = cc + 200 * ( pow(1.15, d) - 1);
                    if ( dd > 10000 ) break;
                    for( double e = 0; e <= 19; ++e ) {
                        double ee = dd + (2000/3) * (pow(1.15, e) - 1);
                        if ( ee > 10000 ) break;
                        for( double f = 0; f <= 11; ++f ) {
                            double ff = ee + (8000/3) * (pow(1.15, f) - 1);
                            if ( ff > 10000 ) break;
                            for( double g = 0; g <= 4; ++g ) {
                                double gg = ff + (40000/3) * (pow(1.15, g) - 1);
                                if ( gg >= 10000 ) break;
                                os << a << ", " << b << ", " 
                                    << c << ", " << d << ", " 
                                    << e << ", " << f << ", " 
                                    << g << "\n";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
local res={}
combinationsstring = "List of Combinations"
--for a = 0, 65 do
        a=0
    for b = 0, 52 do
        for c = 0, 40 do
            for d = 0, 28 do
                for e = 0, 19 do
                    for f = 0, 11 do
                        for g = 0, 4 do
                            if (((1.15^a)-1)+((20/3)*((1.15^b)-1))
                               +((100/3)*((1.15^c)-1))+(200*((1.15^d)-1))
                               +((2000/3)*((1.15^e)-1))+((8000/3)*((1.15^f)-1))
                               +((40000/3)*((1.15^g)-1))) < 10000 then
                                        res[#res+1]={a,b,c,d,e,f,g}
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
--end
```

runs in 30s on my machine and fills around 1 gb of memory. You can't put 66 times that in the 32 bit Lua VM, and in 64 bit LuaVM still the array part of tables is limited to 32 bit integer keys.

I've commented the outermost loop, so you'll need around 30s*66=33min. I'd write that to 66 different files perhaps. The results are held in a table first, which can then be concatenated. Check out:

```
local res={
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
    {8,9,10,11,12,13,14}
}

for k,v in ipairs(res) do
    -- either concatenate each line and produce a huge string
    res[k]=table.concat(v,", ")
  -- or write each line to a file in this loop
end

local text=table.concat(res,"\n")
print(text)
```

printing

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
```